# How to know the coverage for the django application ?

Tags: python, django, code-coverage

I am having a simple django project that contains some applications.Everything works well.Now how do i check code coverage for my project.I have installed coverge-3.5 tool and just tried to know coverage by typing "coverage report" from terminal..It shows some result like

NAME  ----->  (some file in my project)

STMS  ----->  (some number)

MISS  ----->  (some number)

COVER ----->  (some %)

In my case,it will display some result that shows only some of the file names from my project.It didnt shows coverage for all files from my project.How do i make it to show all my file name ????

please suggest any better working coverage tool if you know !

Answer (score 7):

I just got it working like this:

```
coverage run --source=app1,app2 ./manage.py test --settings=path.to.test_settings app1,app2
```

I don't think that this is the intended way to do it since we don't use the ./manage.py test_coverage command at all, but I couldn't find any other way.

Comment: I also got it working like this: `coverage run --include=usermanager/*,witness/*  --omit=.env/*,*/migrations/*,*/__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/models.py,manage.py ./manage.py test usermanager witness --settings=digichainOpen.settings`

Answer (score 6):

first make sure you are using the latest coverage version. than you can do:
assuming your django project lives under project_parent/project, from project_parent run:

```
coverage html --include=project/*.*
```

this will give you a coverage report of your project only (i.e. doesn't output 3rd party lib coverage)

Comment: Thanks for your response.Am using coverage 3.5.If i run coverage html --include=myproject/*.* from the respective path,it returns "No data to report " !!!

Comment: try playing with the path (it works this way for me in the project i use it) but i remember that how to paths with --include wasn't that well documented.

Comment: its not working for me..BUt I had used "coverage run manage.py test" to run all my proj testcases,then I ll use "coverage report" to find out coverage report.It works well.But it outputs 3rd party lib coverage too..Dono how to display coverage for my project testcases alone !!!

Answer (score 3):

I manage to solve this issue with [django_coverage](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-coverage) and django_nose

I added to **INSTALLED_APPS** 'django_coverage' and 'django_nose'

with this on settings.py

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

# Tell nose to measure coverage on the 'foo' and 'bar' apps
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=schedule',
]
```

to install it

> pip install django_coverage
>
> **How do I use it?**
>
> **Install as a Django app Place the entire:**
>
> django_coverage app in your third-party apps directory.
>
> Update your settings.INSTALLED_APPS to include django_coverage.
>
> Include test coverage specific settings in your own settings file.
>
> See settings.py for more detail. Once you've completed all the steps, 
>   you'll have a new custom command available to you via manage.py test_coverage.
>
> It works just like manage.py test.
>
> **Use it as a test runner**
>
> You don't have to install django_coverage as an app if you don't want to. You can
>   simply use the test runner if you like. 
>   Update settings.TEST_RUNNER = 'django_coverage.coverage_runner.CoverageRunner' Include test coverage
>   specific settings in your own settings file. See settings.py for more
>   detail. Run manage.py test like you normally do.