# Testing Google App Engine site for broken links and other request errors

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testing

I'm working on a web app with front end designer and from time we make a mistake that breaks our href links either from typos or small changes that adversely impacting a template or I make silly typo that corrupts a request handler (I'm by not yet an expert in software dev)

[my question is near the end but here's the situation..]

But I wanted to build a tool that I could give my url handlers and site root and have it scan each page for href links and test them.. That way we're not surprised to find broken links as our site gets bigger in pages and functionality.

I was thinking..

- Go through each page
- find href links (and css/js files) or any url that can be followed
- request urls/files and catch errors
- print each error associated with the links in a given page

Then I'd go through my code and templates and find out why links are breaking down...

I've gotten to the point where my code works in my head but I notice mistakes when its up and running but I don't feel like clicking all the links either...

My question is, are there tools dedicated to such testing or does everyone just build their own? (specifically with GAE) Or what is the best practice for not having bad links.

Answer (score 2):

you need to write integration test cases. Write one integration test per url. 
If you have 30 urls than write 30 test functions and in the test functions hit the url and check for the 1. response type 200 and 2. the data type + the values expected i.e. whether a template is expected in return or some json value.

You also need to check for all the possible parameter values associated with a given single url. If you application is django based application than this might be of your help in writing test cases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#testing-tools

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the advice! I will definitely try this out. However I have a question, where do I place this code? Is it independent from my site? So that I can run it against the local dev server and the live server?

Comment: create a new separate integration_tests.py file and you need to add a build rule for that in your BUILD file of the module. After that write your test functions and check for the coverage. You will be good to go with your app only after it is having 100% coverage. For checking test coverage do some search. For your reference I checked there is already one post that you may like to have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524803/how-to-know-the-coverage-for-the-django-application